# What is the simplest way to save small amounts of data (objects) in Android?

Tags: java, android, save

I'm creating an app for a class. The app will allow you to type a title, term, and definition for a Flashcard object, which will then be stored in an arraylist for a FlashcardSet object. What I'm trying to do is save these objects so that I can display them when they are on the Flashcard homepage.

So I understand that I will need a save method and a load method, but where would I call save, and where would I call load? What type of save should I use? I've been looking around and have seen a few, but for this class it will only be a small amount of data, so I don't want to get into SQL and the like.

Comment: you can use `SavePreference` with `GSON` for object

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences to store your data and using it in your app.

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("userId", integer_value);
        editor.putString("userName", string_value);// or put anything you want in this with String type
        editor.apply();
```

And you can get values from it like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
int id = preferences.getInt("userId", 0);// 0 is default values
```